# Model nested under multiple models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

lets say I have the comments model, nested under the posts model.

Now lets say I add a user model, and I want the user to be able to see their comments, in their profile. So I nest the comments model under the posts model as well?

So far - this hasnt been working

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
map.resources :users do |user|
  user.resources :comments
end

map.resources :posts do |user|
  user.resources :comments
end
```

This should work fine. There are a couple caveats:

1. Sometimes the CommentsController will get `params[:user_id]`, and sometimes it will get `params[:post_id]`, depending on the URL. In the comments#index action, for example, you must look up a different set of comments depending on the context.
2. You'll have two different URLs for the same comment. This may or may not be a problem for your site.